# Do i need to specify CSS for media="handheld" and use of CSS media queries if I'm making a simple mobile site for iphone, android, blackberry only?

Tags: xhtml, css, mobile-safari, mobile-website

Do i need to specify CSS for `media="handheld"` and use of CSS media queries `media="only screen and (max-device-width:xxxpx)`"  if I'm making a simple mobile site for iphone, android, blackberry only?

Or `media="all"` or `media="screen"` would be enough?

**I'm only targeting Blackberry 4.6+, iphone and android.**

Comment: I created a CSS for the handheld, and made that the default. <link rel="stylesheet" href="handheld.css" /> Then I went ahead and made the desktop the odd man out with this line <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 801px)" type="text/css" /> The problem was that my Android, an HTC Incredible, seems to report a screen size of 800px. That means what it can handle, not the actual resolution. I'm still testing at http://www.tablemaker.net/pledge/calendar.html

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what kind of devices/browsers are you targeting at. For example s60 browsers behave differently than iPhone, Android, Opera mini and similar browsers. Here is a nice article for your learning pleasures.
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

iPhone and Android don’t load `media="handheld"` stylesheets.

Comment: All version of iPhone and Android?

Comment: @Jitendra: I believe so. The first versions didn’t, so it would be a very inconvenient move on the Mobile Safari team’s part to suddenly change that behaviour. Mobile Safari has been heavily advertised as providing a full internet experience, which wouldn’t be true if it loaded `handheld` stylesheets (which generally, in practice, specify styles for non-smartphones with very limited browsers).

Comment: We query the device's specifications because there's no real way of deciphering a handheld device when phones now have their own choice of browsers. And do you consider an iPad or Kindle handheld? Media type handheld is for the ancient technology called WAP.